# Bash Environmental Variable Not Recognized

Tags: bash, environment

I use Bash for my terminal on Debian. In my `.bashrc`, I've defined an environmental variable like so:

```
SSH_VAULT_VM="ssh-vault"

if [ "$SSH_VAULT_VM" != "" ]; then
    export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~user/.SSH_AGENT_$SSH_VAULT_VM
fi
```

This is to facilitate separating my SSH private/public keys on my bare metal host OS (Qubes OS) as described in [this repo](https://github.com/henn/qubes-app-split-ssh). The way split SSH works in Qubes OS is by hosting the private key in a VM, and the public key in another VM (from which I'm running Emacs). Whenever I use SSH then, a dialog box pop-up appears to confirm accessing the private key.

When I open Emacs from a Bash terminal, the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable is properly defined (as observed in the `initial-environment` variable), and attempts to use the SSH key (e.g., in the `magit` package) succeed with the pop-up confirmation box. However, when I open the Emacs GUI (using X?), the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable is incorrect (instead set to something like: `/tmp/ssh-[some random name]/agent.[3 digit number]`) and attempts to use the SSH key fail.

How can I make Emacs use my `.bashrc` settings such that this split SSH feature will work? I'd be happy to either correct some config to make Emacs load this variable correctly, or overwrite it with the correct value in my `.emacs.d` file. I've tried including something like: `(setenv "SSH_AUTH_SOCK" "/home/user/.SSH_AGENT_ssh-vault")` in my Emacs config, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try putting the definition in your `$HOME/.profile`. It might or might not work (depending on how your desktop environment gets initialized) but it's much more likely to happen with `$HOME/.profile`.

Comment: Emacs can only inherit the environment which was present when it ran.  If you are not running your GUI instance from a bash shell, then your `.bashrc` will obviously have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you want it in the `.profile` instead `.bashrc`. It works from emacs terminal because it's associated with a terminal, thus reads the file first.

Read [Bash startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files).

**edit:** I was assuming that we were talking about user configuration files, something that later I've realized it wasn't that clear. Also, you can use [`.xsessionrc`](https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables) to make those variables available on X sessions.

Comment: The reason I'm including it in my `.bashrc` is to implement split SSH as per [this repo](https://github.com/henn/qubes-app-split-ssh). I've tried moving the variable definition to `.profile` as you recommend, instead of `.bashrc`, but this breaks the functionality of split SSH, even though `initial-environment` is now correct.

Know of another solution?

Comment: please include the repo reference you're trying to make it work and the intended purpose in the question, comments are volatile.

Comment: Updated question to describe split SSH objective

Comment: try putting into `.bash_login` instead, I don't know it it'll work as I have zero experience with Qubes OS and how things are shared among VMs. Anyway isn't an emacs issue, it's just your environment variable isn't set for the X session where you want to access it.

Comment: Typical init scripts (e.g. `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc-common/` on my Fedora 31 system) only look at  `$HOME/.profile` - you can always cheat and source your `$HOME/.bashrc` from your `$HOME/.profile`: it's icky and I would try to avoid it, but desperate times might call for desperate measures.

Comment: Note that the bash manual does say source your ~/.bashrc from your ~/.bash_profile so it is not at all icky but the approved way of setting up bash.

Comment: The reason for `$HOME/.bashrc` is to define aliases and functions that are *NOT* inherited by subshells. And yes, you source it in `$HOME/.bash_profile` so you can have them defined in your login shell as well - that's not the icky part. The icky part is setting env variables in `$HOME/.bashrc`: those are typically defined and exported in the profile and inherited by subshells and they should not be defined in `$HOME/.bashrc`.